# Leopard geckos being housed together

Tags: multi-pet-families, containment, leopard-geckos

Can I house a leopard gecko with one that has lost her tail? I have a 30 gallon long tank that she’s currently in and there’s 3 hides so there’s lots of space to hide.

Answer (score 2):

**The most important priority is to make sure that whatever stress caused her to drop her tail is identified and corrected.** In addition to obvious injury and health problems, Leos can get stressed by things in their environment; Remember every Leo is different and there isn't always one size fits all answers.  First thing to do is to make sure you know what caused her to loose her tail and evaluate if there is anything causing her stress in her environment.

One possible stressor could be how big of tank she is in, it's unlikely that caused the loss of her tail but it could be adding to it or her recovery.  A larger tank than necessary can make some Leos feel a little insecure or unsafe.  A 30 gallon tank is a little big for (2) Geckos (I use a 20 gallon) and huge for just (1) Gecko. Single Geckos only need a 10 gallon tank. A good fit tank size also is from my experience easier to keep consistent temps on each side.

**In regards to housing them together it depends, I need more information to answer...**

What caused her to lose her tail and how long ago did it happen?
Have the 2 leopard Geckos lived together before and was there every any aggression or bullying(chasing her out of hides, laying on top of her alot, competition over food) ?

What genders are they ?  As a rule, you should never house 2 males together.  A male and female can be OK if they co-exist well and are healthy enough to withstand breeding, if it happens, and you are ready to handle it if they bred.  2 Females if they co-exist well can usually be housed together.

Comment: You think that a tank can be too big? I have no experiences with geckos, but isn't that a bit ... counterintuitive? The wild geckos have to feel very insecure, right? But I understand your argument that smaller tanks are easier to keep consistent temps.

Comment: Leopard Geckos are one of the easiest reptiles to care for and, depending on the individual Gecko, can thrive in varied conditions which is part of the the reason there is alot of conflicting information out there regarding leopard gecko husbandry. A larger tank size may not be an issue for some Larger tanks tend to cause the geckos to stray away from their proper heat and hide box.

Comment: I note this because you have one that has lost a tail from some type of stress so evaluating possible changes you can make in the environment to reduce the stress will benefit her, whether it is to  separate her, reduce the size of her tank or other. More info why she lost her tail would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can co-habitat your leopard geckos. The general rule of thumb is the best size tank for one leopard gecko is a ten gallon tank and +5 gallon for each gecko you want to put into. That means

- 1 gecko = 10 gallon tank
- 2 geckos = 15 gallon tank
- 3 geckos = 20 gallon tank

Here is more information about [providing captive leopard gecko habitat](https://thepetenthusiast.com/leopard-gecko-habitat/)